# PHP - Can not open and write to a file using fopen and fwrite in Ubuntu

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying the following code to write to a file.

```
<?php

$path = getcwd();
$fp = fopen($path . 'data.txt', 'w') or die("Can not open the file");
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);
```

Initially the file permissions on **data.txt** was **-rw-r--r--** and causing the following error:

> fopen(data.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied

So I changed file permissions to **-rw-rw-rw-**, but nothing is happening now.
It is neither writing to a file nor showing any error.

Can anybody please help me what has went wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[`getcwd()`](https://php.net/getcwd) does not contain the final slash. So you have to add it :

```
$fp = fopen($path . '/data.txt', 'w') or die("Can not open the file");
```

Comment: Oh yes, slash was missing. Thanks a lot for noticing it. It is now working. Cheers!